# I want to embellish a class from a python module. How do I do this?

Tags: python

I am using a class from a module that I import. I want to extend this class: add some more attributes/methods. However, I want to retain all the functionality, including all possible constructors, of the original class.

Here is one way I can do it:

```
class Extension(module.ModuleClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        newargument = kwargs.pop("myarg")
        super(Extension, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.newargument = newargument
```

This seems to work, but has a minor syntactic sugar issue and the following much bigger isssue. ModuleClass overloads the "`+`" etc. operators. Of course, Extension now benefits from this overloading, but as a result of how these are implemented in ModuleClass, the result is of type ModuleClass, not Extension. That is, for `Extension` objects `a` and `b`, the result `a + b` is well defined, but has type `ModuleClass`, not `Extension`. This is crucially important..

Is there a better way to achieve extension such as what I am looking for? Better in the senses of type-preservation as a result of operations, easier to debug down the line, easier to maintain, and more efficient?

Specifically, is there a way to use composition rather than inheritance? I.e., to write a wrapper class that **has as attribute** a `ModuleClass`, is able to redirect all attributes (including methods) to the contained `ModuleClass`, but handles functionality related to new arguments etc. itself?

The following is my failed attempt at using composition to solve the problem:

```
class Extension(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.myarg = kwargs.pop('timestamp')
        self.mclass = module.ModuleClass(*args, **kwargs)
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if (name == 'mclass'):
            return self.mclass
        elif (name == 'myarg'):
            return self.myarg
        else:
            return getattr(self.mclass, name)
```

But this fails to achieve what I want to (make `Extension` look like `Module` with extensions). What care is to be taken?

**Minor** syntactic sugar issue: the constructor arguments now have to include "myarg = something", which is not the most desirable. (I would have preferred if i could have the constructor take the first argument, OR an argument specified with "myarg = something" to initialize self.newargument. However, this is a minor issue. Ideally, I would like to support constructor calls of the form

```
Extension(validValueForMyarg, validStuffToInitModuleClass)
Extension(validStuffToInitModuleClass, myarg = validValueForMyarg)
```

and, where it makes sense,

```
Extension(myarg = validValueForMyarg, validStuffToInitModuleClass)
```

Comment: How would you like it to behave if `myarg` isn't supplied?

Comment: I would like the constructor to error if `myarg` is not specified. In other words, I would like `myarg` to be a required argument.

Comment: @TimBeaver: Can you clarify exactly which kinds of call syntaxes you would like to support?

Comment: @BrenBarn : I would like to support `Extension(validValueForMyArg, anyStuffThatIsValidToInitModuleClass)`, `Extension(anyStuffThatIsValidToInitModuleClass, myarg = valueForMyArg)`, and, where it makes sense,  `Extension(myarg = valueForMyArg,  anyStuffThatIsValidToInitModuleClass)`

Comment: @TimBeaver: Please edit that information into your question, since it's crucial.

Comment: `Extension(myarg = validValueForMyarg, validStuffToInitModuleClass)` never makes sense. Python doesn't allow positional args after keyword args (and rightly so, imo).

Comment: @jpmc26 : it does make sense when `validStuffToInitModuleClass` is of the form `this = that`

Comment: @TimBeaver I tend to fall down on the side of it's too confusing to keep the arguments straight when you allow mixing of positional and keyword arg order. (If it's getting messy in that order, just do all keyword args and be done with it.) I suspect that the reasons for Python's implementation are more technical (probably simplifies the parser). Regardless, it's explicitly disallowed in Python. You can't do it. So it doesn't make sense *in the context of Python*. ...If you mean it's supposed to be a list of keyword args, then I would expand the example out to make that clear.

Comment: @jpmc26 - that's okay, I have a bigger question about this - edited my question for that.

Comment: If you're looking to write a proxy object, google around or look on this site for questions about how to write a proxy object in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a required argument to `Extension.__init__` like so:

```
class Extension(module.ModuleClass):
    def __init__(self, myarg, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Extension, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.newargument = myarg
```

Comment: I did try this but could not get it to work. Certainly calls to the constructor of the form `Extension(valueForMyarg, otherStuff)` work, but calls of the form `Extension(stuff, myarg = valueForMyarg)` fail with the error `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'myarg'`

Comment: And of course calls of the form `Extension(myarg = valueForMyArg, stuff)` fail with `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`

Comment: Of course; `myarg` isn't a keyword argument. You can't have a keyword argument that can also be the first positional argument, just like `def foo(arg1=1, arg2)` is illegal.

Comment: @chepner What about the latter example? Why doesn't `Extension(stuff, myarg=valueForMyarg)` work?

Comment: The value of `stuff` is assigned to the first parameter, `myarg`. You can't assign it another value later using it as a keyword argument.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work

```
class Extension(module.ModuleClass):
    def __init__(self,*args, myarg=None, **kwargs):
        if myarg is None:
            raise ValueError('myarg is required')
        super(Extension, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.newargument = myarg
```